# `toLocaleString()` not rendering inside number input when value greater than 1 million

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

In this code, I have the value 1000000 (one million) which I format with `toLocaleString('en-gb')` to get `1,000,000`.

Then I print that value as text and it works as expected, also when I use that const as the value of a text input.
But when using the value in a numeric input, it just doesn't render. It works though when the value is < 1 million.

[image]

Inspecting the html, I see the value is correct:
[image]

In addition, when trying to type the value in that numeric input, it doesn't register values after 4 digits.

Any ideas what's going on? I wonder if it could be that after 999.000 the number will have two thousand-separators

teh codez (also in this playground https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8ufbe1?file=App.tsx):

```js
export default function App() {
  const value = (1000000).toLocaleString('en-gb');
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(value);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(Number(e.target.value).toLocaleString('en-gb'))}
      />
      <input type="text" value={inputValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I see there are libraries like [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) but seems like the native way should do what I need.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The `value` property of a number input will be empty if the string value of the input cannot be parsed as a valid number in the form of a JavaScript numeric constant. That is, it has to have the same form as a JavaScript number, with no commas, and the "." character as the decimal separator.

Comment: That's not a React thing, it's the way browsers work with that type of `<input>`.

Comment: @Pointy I think you are right on that comment. Will leave it open a little more but I think your answer might be the correct one. Thank you for that :) 
I know is not a react thing, just did that example in react to have an reproducible example in Stackblitz, and then stumbled upon that react library.

Comment: `after 999.000` I notice you use a full stop as a thousands separator.  The number type understands it to be a decimal point.  Having two decimal points is invalid for a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works before reaching 1,000 because 1,000 is where you have to add a comma. At 999 you still satisfy the requirements of an input with type number you're inserting only a number `999`. Since HTML only really allows strings they let you pass with `"999"` vs `999` the pure numeric version.

In any case. I don't think you want to use the `type='number'` it works pretty poorly and shows the ticker up and down. If this is a mobile focused decision consider using `type='tel'`.

What you can also do is attempt to manually mask the behavior by putting 2 inputs on top of each other. Or you can use an input type='tel' `onFocus={() => Number(inputValue)}` and `onBlur={() => inputValue.toLocaleString('en-gb')}` and that will be the start to getting where you want to get.

This type of stuff usually is slightly messy and will take a bit to perfect. The UI can easily get wonky, and the problem is not so perfectly solved:

- We want to enforce that users only type numbers and make it easy for them to do so (especially mobile)
- We want the numbers to appear as strings.
  Those 2 priorities are at odds with each other.

If you don't want to directly import a library which contains this I'd strongly suggest you read their source code.

Some potential resources:
https://cchanxzy.github.io/react-currency-input-field/ (Note that just the single component is 600 lines long)

including this excerpt:

````
const handleOnFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>): number => {
      onFocus && onFocus(event);
      return stateValue ? stateValue.length : 0;
    };

    /**
     * Handle blur event
     *
     * Format value by padding/trimming decimals if required by
     */
    const handleOnBlur = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      const {
        target: { value },
      } = event;

      const valueOnly = cleanValue({ value, ...cleanValueOptions });

      if (valueOnly === '-' || !valueOnly) {
        setStateValue('');
        onBlur && onBlur(event);
        return;
      }

      const fixedDecimals = fixedDecimalValue(valueOnly, decimalSeparator, fixedDecimalLength);

      const newValue = padTrimValue(
        fixedDecimals,
        decimalSeparator,
        decimalScale !== undefined ? decimalScale : fixedDecimalLength
      );

      const numberValue = parseFloat(newValue.replace(decimalSeparator, '.'));

      const formattedValue = formatValue({
        ...formatValueOptions,
        value: newValue,
      });

      if (onValueChange) {
        onValueChange(newValue, name, {
          float: numberValue,
          formatted: formattedValue,
          value: newValue,
        });
      }

      setStateValue(formattedValue);

      onBlur && onBlur(event);
    };
    ```
````